# Getting docker.sock in joyent triton

Tags: joyent, triton

I am trying to setup `jwilder/nginx-proxy` docker container on joyent's triton platform. This container needs access to `docker.sock` to read information about its environment. Basically it needs to do

```
docker up -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro ...
```

On triton this fails like

```
Invalid host volume paths found: must be in the form "http://host/path:/container_path": ["/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:rw"]
```

Any ideas how I could inject docker.sock into my container on triton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triton doesn't currently support docker.sock. You have to go through the DOCKER_HOST TCP port. If you would like this to be a feature, send them a tweet, email or github ticket.

Full disclosure: I work for Joyent.